# Running a compass task with gulp results in a LoadError

Tags: ruby, macos, sass, gulp

When running a compass task with Gulp (on OSX), I receive the following error. I've tried installing specific versions of both compass and sass (in various orders) without any notable effect.

```
[17:25:46] LoadError on line ["54"] of /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- compass/import-once/activate
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace


events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: Compass failed
  at Transform.<anonymous> (/Users/liamegan/Projects/WTC/nintendo.wethecollective.com/html/Websites/Kids/web/node_modules/gulp-compass/index.js:37:28)
  at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/liamegan/Projects/WTC/nintendo.wethecollective.com/html/Websites/Kids/web/node_modules/gulp-compass/lib/compass.js:136:7)
  at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
  at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

My compass version is 0.12.7 and my sass version is 3.3.13 however I've also tried with sass 3.2.19.

My sass gulp process is as follows:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp
    .src('./_src/sass/screen.scss')
    .pipe(compass({
      config_file: './config.rb'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'))
})
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this with the following:

```
sudo gem uninstall sass
sudo gem uninstall compass
sudo gem install sass
sudo gem install compass --pre
```

This installed the prerelease version of compass which works with the latest, stable version of sass.